# Google Analytics 4 (GA4) - Analytics Data API - When will this be out of Alpha, Beta?

Tags: google-analytics-api

Based on the Analytics Data API Banner ("Keep in mind that these APIs are pre-release and subject to change. Code built using these APIs should not be pushed to production. While we will try to notify you of upcoming changes, you should expect to encounter breaking changes before the APIs are publicly released."), the APIs are pre-release and subject to change.

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data

When is the Analytics Data API expected to be out of Alpha?

When is it expected to be out of Beta?

Is this timeline a few months, a few quarters, or will it take a year or more to stabilize and publish?

---

Followup question, if this is going to take some time to move out of Alpha / Beta, do you expect to allow "App+Web" upgrades to downgrade back to "Universal Analytics"?

I have also sent an email to the address in the documentation with no response.

Thanks!

Comment: Added a Question into the dedicated Analytics Forum as well:    https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/81874434?hl=en

Comment: Update: The Google Analytics Data API is now available at Beta stability: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brie,

I don't believe there is a public timeline on the API release cycle, but we hope to move on to Beta fairly soon. As for your second question, it is not possible to downgrade GA4 (formely App+Web) properties back to "Universal Analytics", as they are fundamentally different.

Thanks,
Ilya

The Google Analytics Team

Answer (score 0):

I imagine most developers are waiting until the official release of the API before incorporating it into their workflows. But I would recommend that we all spend some time testing the API and provide feedback to Google. That way we can point out any issues and suggest features that will be of value.

For example, I want to pull up to 50+ dimensions and metrics but the API limits runReport requests to 9 dimensions and 10 metrics. I doubt Google will budge on those quotas so I figured I'd run multiple queries and merge them programmatically. Unfortunately, that's not a viable approach since there is no universal key/column available to effectively join data across those queries.

However, if the Google Analytics session id were a dimension it could serve as that universal column. So I made an entry under the Google Analytics Issue tracker requesting just that (feel free to star [Issue#: 188980721](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188980721)).

So get involved, the sooner we do and vocalize our needs (especially at this stage of development) the more likely the API will meet those goals.